# What is the best way to identify the in-app purchase is successfully completed or not?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I implemented in-app purchase in my android application. It is working fine, but some times(rare cases) the transactions are not successfully completed. The main problem is money is debiting from account after that i am unable to predict what was the wrong.

Please help me.  This app is already in play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've overridden `onActivityResult` and checked the `requestCode` and `resultCode` like is documented at http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html, right?